# Swift What is the model file use for and how does it work?

Tags: swift

I saw some developer using User.swift or Post.swift. What is it use for and why it seems like every developer had it.

Some code i find online https://github.com/dasoga/chat-firebase/blob/master/ChatRealTime/Model/User.swift

```
import UIKit

class User: NSObject {
var id: String?
var name: String?
var email: String?
var profileImageUrl: String?
}
```

Comment: Provide a link to the original code. Also your question is too vague: "What is it and how it works" is sort of open-ended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of a model class is to encapsulate the data used by app in its own class, offering a cleaner separation of the model from the controller and the view. See [Model-View-Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) in Apple's *Cocoa Core Competencies.* Or see [Model object](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ModelObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH31-SW1).

But setting aside these broader design principles, let's consider your `User` class: This is a class that encapsulates a series of properties, namely an identifier, name, email address, and image URL. So, why use this `User` type, rather than individual properties and/or standard collections?

Let's consider the alternatives, which is illustrative of why a model object like `User` can be powerful:

- Consider an app which maintained a list of users. An array of `User` objects is far more convenient than, say, separate arrays of identifiers, names, emails, etc. For example, what if you wanted to sort the list of users by name? If you had all of these properties in different arrays, keeping track of them would be very complicated.
- So, let's say that you recognized that keeping these various properties all together was powerful, so you decided to use simple dictionary to accomplish this. Then an array of users could be represented as an array of dictionaries. That solves the previous problem.

  But it introduces other problems. For example, it's now incumbent upon you, the programmer, to use the right keys for this dictionary, and the compiler can't offer you any clues as to what it expects what the keys for this dictionary should be, much less any rules that govern the type of data associated with those keys.

  Worse, you might have business rules associated with this `User` object, namely that `id` and `name` might be required, but that the email address and the image URL are optional. Furthermore, you might want to apply some business rules to the email address and URL to make sure they're valid. Or you might say that it's valid to change a user's name or email address, but not to change their `id`. This all sort of logic can be encapsulated within the `User` object, but if you're using a simple dictionary, it's hard to capture those business rules effectively.

  For example, I might suggest refactoring your `User` class to capture some of these business rules:

  ```
  class User {
      let id: String         // note use of `let`, not `var`, meaning you can't change this
      var name: String       // note no `?`, meaning that this is required
      var email: String?     // note use of `?`, meant that this _is_ optional
      var imageURL: NSURL?   // note use of `NSURL`, which more strongly captures/validates a URL string

      init(id: String, name: String, email: String?, imageURL: NSURL?) {
          self.id = id
          self.name = name
          self.email = email
          self.imageURL = imageURL
      }
  }
  ```

  This is now a nice simple `User` type that, with very limited code, enforces all sorts of business logic (e.g. `id` is required and immutable, `name` is required but mutable, `email` and `imageURL` are optional and mutable). Clearly, you could go much further with this class definition, encapsulating all sorts of other business requirements.

  But the beauty of this is that when use this `User` class in your code, these rules are enforced at compile time, eliminating all sorts of programming problems before they occur. The properties are strongly-typed and the mutability and optionality of the various properties are nicely encapsulated in this simple type.

Bottom line, with well designed model types, it's easier to write good code that safely uses and interacts with these model classes.

Comment: Thanks for answer my question. I would like to ask how can it be use in function or code? Any example?

Comment: You use it like any other object in your code. You instantiate it when you want to use it (e.g. `let user1 = User(42, "Rob", "rob@example.com", nil)`, or you can build arrays however you want (e.g. `var users = [User](); users.append(user1)`, etc. There's not really anything to it. Just use your model objects like any other object in your app.